# DRF Spectacular - @extend_schema subclass method for Serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

Im using DRF_SPECTACTULAR to generate swagger DOC from my DRF Project.
I have a GenericViewSet that implement CRUD methods.

Over each ones, I have extend_schema decorator.
Take this one as example:

```
@extend_schema(
            # extra parameters added to the schema
            parameters=[
                OpenApiParameter(name = "jwt_token", description="JSON Web Token", required=True, type=str),
                OpenApiParameter(name = "id", type = OpenApiTypes.STR, location=OpenApiParameter.PATH , description = "ID "),
            ],
            methods=["GET"],
            description = 'Return a serialized User',
            request     = JWTRequestSerializer,
            responses   = { 200: GenericResponseSerializer },
        )
def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
```

I Have a lot of ViewSet for every Models that extends the Generic and override some methods to make it specific for the model.

I need something like this for the Serializer in extend_schema.
In the example, I have GenericResponseSerializer but I need every subclasses that extends this SuperClass, return its own specific Serializer.

I've tried with a static method:

```
@staticmethod
def getRetrieveSerializer():
    return GenericResponseSerializer()

...
responses   = { 200: getRetrieveSerializer },
...
```

It works well but it always return the SuperClasses method even if Im extending it.
Unfortunally in decorator, I cant access self so I cant use a method that is overwritten at runtime.

Is there a way to reach this goal? Maby with reflection?